# Uncaught LateInitializationError: Field 'deviceToken' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

Error: Uncaught LateInitializationError: Field 'deviceToken' has not been initialized.
Not sure what went wrong here.

```
late String deviceToken;
      var registerRepo = GoogleSignInRepo();
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> gettoken() async {
    final String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    return token!;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    gettoken().then((value) {
      deviceToken = value;
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: It means that you're using uninitialized `deviceToken` in your other part of code. Please be aware that `gettoken().then` will initialized `deviceToken` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error pretty much tells you the problem:

`Error: Uncaught LateInitializationError: Field 'deviceToken' has not been initialized.`

Flutter is **null-safe**, therefore if you define a variable you need to assign a value to it since the value by definition is not allowed to be null. Keep in mind that the `late` keyword only tells you that the variable will be initialized at runtime instead of compile time.

This means that some other part of your code probably accesses `deviceToken` before it was initialized in your `Future`.

You can solve it like this:

```
// Assign a value (empty string in this case).  
String deviceToken = "";
```

Another solution would be to make your field nullable and this is probably the better solution in your case.

```
// Null is a valid value and will not cause a error. 
String? deviceToken;
```

Or: Make sure the field was initialized before you access it.

For further reference this article might help you out:
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: Thank you, I got an idea how to fix the same problem.